# Mysqli Changed Rows value of 0 when actually 1

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

mysqli::$affected_rows/mysqli_affected_row() is returning 0 for me for some reason.
This i my function:

```
function set_timezone_value($sUsername, $sTimeZone){

    $_SESSION["timezone_value"] = $sTimeZone;

    //get a connection to the LDAP db
    $db_con = get_db_con(LDAP, TRUE);

    $sQuery = "UPDATE user_info " .
              "SET sTimeZone = '". $db_con->real_escape_string($sTimeZone) . "' " .
              "WHERE uid = '". $db_con->real_escape_string($sUsername) ."'";
    do_query($sQuery, $db_con);
    var_dump($db_con->info);
    $iAffectedRows = $db_con->affected_rows;
    $db_con->close();

    return $iAffectedRows;
}
```

do_query and get_db_con are simply wrappers for mysqli->query and new mysqli with additional code to send emails if there is an error.

That var_dump is printing `string(40) "Rows matched: 1 Changed: 0 Warnings: 0"` which indicates that the row is being found but not changed. This is incorrect though since when I view the row in phpMyAdmin before and after the code is run, the row is actually updated to the new time zone, and the rest of the site functions with the correct timezone. Despite this, whether I use the procedural or the OO style, affected_rows and info indicate that no change to the row was made.

Is there something I'm messing up in my code?

Comment: Are you sure there is no SQL query between the execution of your query and your call to the number of affected rows? Any other query executed (e.g. for population the `$db_con->info` variable) can change the return value of `mysqli_affected_row()` as this function is bound to the last query.

Comment: No other calls, this is being run on a single threaded system and the function calls are right after each other. I've also isolated the issue to just call only that function, and it still happens. The weird thing is, I use these same functions elsewhere in the exact same manner with different results.

Answer (score 0):

The behavior you describe is the default. An `UPDATE` statement with values matching the existing row results in zero rows affected. This is quite annoying as you do not know whether the record to update has been deleted in the meantime or there are simply no changes.

If you use PHP PDO and PHP 5.3+, there is an option to change that behavior:

```
$options = array('MYSQL_ATTR_FOUND_ROWS' => true);
```

Setting this flag returns the number of found (matched) rows, not the number of changed rows.
See http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php and http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php#104930

Comment: The row does not match the values though, and I've run the generated sql command through phpmyadmin and it returns one affected row. Current value of 'America/Chicago' and being changed to 'America/Los_Angeles' still yields matched 1, changed 0.